# how to display the download url when image is uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

This code uploads the file successfully but the download url is not displayed once it is done

The console shows the error

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
 <script>

   var config = {
 // Initialize Firebase
};

   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   var snapshot;

var  uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');
fileButton.addEventListener('change' , function(e) {

var file= e.target.files[0];
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('pics/' + file.name);

var task = storageRef.put(file);   


task.on('state_changed' , 

function progress(){
    var percentage = (task.snapshot.bytesTransferred / task.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;



},
function error(err){

},
function complete(res)
{ 
    console.log("Complete Response :" + res);

     }
);


});
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
  });



 </script>
```

*** i want the download link to be printed once the file is uploaded ***

**The console shows the error**
[image]

Comment: Hi Varun, 
Please share the console response(error).
Alongwith how you are handling the below
--------------------------------------------
function error(err){

},
function complete(){

}

Comment: try to add:

-------------------------------------
function complete(res){
 console.log("Complete Response :" + res);
}
----------------------
and share Console Log

Comment: modification done and updated but still i haven't got the expected output

Comment: I have shared the answer, please check and try to implement it. If needed, share your comment, will try to help further.

Comment: Continuing to post the same question over and over is likely to get you banned from Stack Overflow. If your first post on a problem isn't getting you the help you need, follow up there. Clarify, ask questions, interact, but don't simply repost the same question. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160902/241432.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

> You need a slight modification in your code near.

```
function progress(){
    var percentage = (task.snapshot.bytesTransferred / task.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;



},
function error(err){

},
function complete(res)
{ 
    console.log("Complete Response :" + res);

     }
,function(){
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
  });
}
```

Ref Firebase:

```
// File or Blob named mountains.jpg
var file = ...

// Create the file metadata
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {

  // A full list of error codes is available at
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    ...

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
      break;
  }
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: i used the second Ref Firebase method but it also shows up an error ** Uncaught ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined** 
and the progress bar is also not working pls help

Comment: `task.on('state_changed' , 

function progress(){
    var percentage = (task.snapshot.bytesTransferred / task.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;

    

},
function error(err){

},
function complete(res){
    console.log("file available at"+res);

}
,function(){
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
    document.writeln(downloadURL);
  });
}
);
});`


this code shows error **invalid argument count**

Comment: There is a declaration and initialization of storagRef is missing help me out pls